# how to create my own button with crudbooster in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4, crudbooster

I have a button called "Buat SPT". I just want this button be linked to another form view:

[image: View]

I don't know how to change this code:

```
<a href='{{Route("AdminCmsUsersControllerGetIndex")}}'>create SP</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your button with a tag

```html
<a href='{{Route("AdminCmsUsersControllerGetIndex")}}'><button> Buat SPT </button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

make route for that in routes/web.php

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/BuatSPT', '\App\Http\Controllers\ControllerName@BuatSPT');
```

//controller

```
function index() {
        return view('folder/view_file_name');
    }
```

//view

```
<a href="{{ URL::asset('BuatSPT')}}" class="btn btn-success">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Buat SPT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

web.php file

```
 Route::any("/admin-cms-users",function(){
     return view("index");
 })->name("AdminCmsUsersControllerGetIndex");
```